# Ner Mitzwa (MaHaRa"L), Machon Yerushalayim Edition

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, chanuka, internet, maharal

Edited/Footnoted by Rabbi [Yehoshua Hartman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehoshua_Hartman), the Machon Yerushalayim editions of many (most/all?) MaHaRa"L publications have been made available in recent times. If one investigates the Internet, one will find that many of them are available on [www.Hebrewbooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org)... Does anyone know if Maharal's sefer on חנוכה known as *Ner Mitzvah* is also available for free download?

Comment: These are not from the *Machon Yerushalayim* edition, but here are a couple of links to the text of *Ner Mitzva* online from the [Daat website](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/shabat/hanuka/ner-2.htm) and from the [Tsel Harim website](http://www.tsel.org/torah/ner).

Comment: It would appear not, but the standard version is there http://hebrewbooks.org/14191